# Codeigniter joins

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hello im writing a simple blog and i want to take the username from the guy who wrote the post using codeigniter's active record.

So far i have this model:

```
function get_posts($num = 20, $start = 0)
{
    $this->db
         ->select('*')
         ->from('blog')
         ->join('users', 'users.user_id = blog.creator_id')
         ->where('public', TRUE)
         ->order_by('post_id', 'DESC')
         ->limit($num, $start);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

From the codeigniter docs i found this join example but i cant figure out how it works. I just want to get the username from the users table using the user id.

### The database

Users table: `id, username, e-mail, password, name`

Posts table: `id, public, title, body, creator_id`

Comment: Somehow i'm not getting any errors. However im not getting what i want. This is my first time using joins.

Answer (score 1):

You can take only `username` in the select field.

Also, get all the `usernames` in an array.

```
function get_posts($num = 20, $start = 0)
{
    $this->db
         ->select('users.username')
         ->from('blog')
         ->join('users', 'users.user_id = blog.creator_id')
         ->where('public', TRUE)
         ->order_by('post_id', 'DESC')
         ->limit($num, $start);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $usernames = array();
    foreach ($query->result_array() as $curr) {
      $usernames[] = $curr['username'];
    }
    $usernames = array_unique($usernames);
    return $usernames;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look on **users.user_id** must be **users.id** as per the your DB

```
function get_posts($num = 20, $start = 0)
{
$this->db
     ->select('*')
     ->from('blog')
     ->join('users', 'users.id = blog.creator_id')
     ->where('public', TRUE)
     ->order_by('post_id', 'DESC')
     ->limit($num, $start);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
}
```

Comment: hello, this returns only '1' which is the id. How can i get the name?

Comment: make sure the table **"blog"** or **"posts"**

Comment: in query you have return **->from('blog')** and the database you have define with 2 tables in that 2nd table is **posts**

Answer (score 0):

According to your table users, coulmn user_id does not exists, you have id only so change your code from `users.user_id` to `user.id`

```
function get_posts($num = 20, $start = 0)
{
    $this->db
         ->select('*')
         ->from('blog')
         ->join('users', 'users.id = blog.creator_id')
         ->where('public', TRUE)
         ->order_by('post_id', 'DESC')
         ->limit($num, $start);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```